# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to populate an array with numbers starting from 2016, ending at current year.

My method looks like this

```
  generateYears () {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    let y = 2016;
    console.log(currentDate.getFullYear());
    for (y = 2016; y <= currentDate.getFullYear(); y++) {
        this.testYears.push(y);
    }
    console.log(this.testYears);
  }
```

and testYears was declared with

```
  testYears: number[];
```

I have tried to declare it any[] but got same error.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you get this error in compile-time or in runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `number[]` syntax simply sets the type of the variable, not the value. Typescript types are removed before runtime. When your code is run, `testYears` has never been defined with an actual value and so is undefined.

To fix, simply define `testYears` as

```
public testYears: number[] = [];
```

This way, `testYears` has both a type (`number[]`) and a value (`[]`)